# CSS positioning - stop element movement with screen size

Tags: css, textbox, scroll, css-position, positioning

A bit of a newbie question, but I've had this problem for a while now and i need it fixed. Hopefully one of you guys can help.

I have a textbox near the bottom of my page. It's position is fixed, however, whenever I resize the browser window, it moves with the bottom of the page.  I've tried it with absolute and rlative positioning too, but still, same problem. Ive been reading up on CSS positioning, and assumed I understood it, until this little problem.

I have a header bar at the top of my page which is position: fixed, and that doesn't move, so I'm wondering what the difference is?

Illustrations of the problem are here: 
The bottom image is the normal view, and the top is the textbox moving ahen the window is shrunk.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM8TU.jpg

My textbox is named "typetextbox" and the header banner is "cfbanner"

The CSS is:

```
#cfbanner{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: -130px;
z-index:-20

}

#typetextbox{
left: 130px;
bottom: 50px;
position: fixed;
width: 850px;
```

Im sure this is easily fixable. A little help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Just remove 
position: fixed;

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of your typetextbox seems right, since you specify the box to be fixed and the distance to the bottom to be 50px.

W3Schools.com writes:

> An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

So if you shrink your browser window, the text box will stick to the bottom of your window, hence, as you wrote:

> it moves with the bottom of the page

If you want the box to stick at the given position, remove the "bottom" attribute and specify the "top" attribute, just as you did it with "#cfbanner".